# Inaccurate result of an arithmetic operation when execute in procedure or function (oracle)

Tags: plsql, numbers, decimal-point

I'm trying to calculate item affected on employee salary but the result of arithmetic operation is inaccurate as example return 99.99999999999999 instead of 100  . This happen only inside procedure or function but work correctly in case in separated sql query .

EX :

```
CREATE TABLE SS_TEST_CUT
(
  CUT  NUMBER
);

create or replace procedure ss_test (x1 number , x2 number , num out number) 
as 
x number ; 
begin 
    x := 100; 
    num := (x/30) *(30 - x1 - x2); 
    insert into ss_test_cut (cut) values (trunc (num,2));
end;

select cut from  ss_test_cut;
```

Actual result is : 99.99
Expected result   : 100

Out side the procedure gives the expected result .

`select (100/30 ) * 30 from dual;`
output : 100

why and how to avoid this with out round the number because other numbers have fraction part ?
Thanks,

Comment: `declare tot number(10);` that is, if you don't care about precision, if you do `declare tot number(10,5);` or any other ... let me know if that works.

Comment: @g00dy. Your suggestion wil certainly work but the problem is OP doesnot know what he want. :-). Am still waiting for `actual result` definition from him

Comment: @XING - true, no actual result definition yet ...

Comment: Please share the "separated sql query" which works "correctly".

Comment: See my answer below. [This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a157f/1) demonstrates that the original calculation *always* produces a result of 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999000 - you just have to format it wide enough to see it. I suspect that whatever SQL tool you're using rounded the result from the query, while the PL/SQL result wasn't rounded. If you re-order the operations in the calculation as shown in my answer, you get the expected result.

Comment: @sahar your formula correctly gives 99.9 recurring and has nothing to do with procedures giving incorrect results. Perhaps you could edit your question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Re-order the operations in the calculation to avoid intermediate rounding:

```
create or replace procedure ss_test (x1 number , x2 number , num out number) 
as 
x number ; 
begin 
    x := 100; 
    num := (x * (30 - x1 - x2)) / 30; 
    insert into ss_test_cut (cut) values (trunc (num,2));
end;
```

Works as intended, assuming x1 and x2 are zero.

Best of luck.

Comment: Excellent point. I guess 99.9 recurring isn't the same thing as 100 when you round down. However @sahar suggested that his caclulation gave different results in SQL and in PL/SQL with PL/SQL giving incorrect results, which he has not demonstrated. I guess your answer resolves the actual issue and the rest is an XY problem.

Comment: [I just created an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a157f/1) which demonstrates that the problem is the calculation rather than where and how it's invoked. I added a comment to the question to bring this to OP's attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** OK, now that the question is slightly clearer, the procedure is producing 99.9 recurring, which is not the same thing as 100, especially when you round down. However I still don't see PL/SQL giving an incorrect result where SQL is correct. As Bob's answer shows, `100 / 30 * 30` and `(100 * 30) / 30` are two different things.

---

This is a display formatting issue *(Edit: unless you round down...)*:

```
SQL> select 100 / 30 * 30 from dual;

 100/30*30
----------
       100

SQL> select to_char(100 / 30 * 30) from dual;

TO_CHAR(100/30*30)
----------------------------------------
99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

99.9 recurring and 100 are effectively the same thing.

Here is another example to show that the result inside the procedure is the same as when using SQL directly:

```
SQL> create table demo (label varchar2(10), result number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into demo values ('SQL', 100 / 30 * 30);

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2      num number;
  3  begin
  4      num := 100 / 30 * 30;
  5
  6      insert into demo values ('PL/SQL', num);
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select label, result, to_char(result) from demo;

LABEL          RESULT TO_CHAR(RESULT)
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
SQL               100 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999
PL/SQL            100 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Even what @g00dy  wrote will bring in what is needed in OP question. Not sure what point you want to make with this answer,

Comment: @William Robertson when debug in procedure the watch value is 99.999999999 and use this result in other calculation with out saving it in a table the final result will be according to 99.9999999

Comment: @sahar that is your assumption. Most likely the debugger displays all values as strings (see what it does with dates, for example). 99.9 recurring is just how it looks as a string, 100 is how it looks as a number.

Comment: please try this show that affected on calculation not only display . see the value stored in the table                          CREATE TABLE SS_TEST_CUT
(
  CUT  NUMBER
)                               create or replace procedure ss_test (x1 number , x2 number , num out number) 
as 
x number ; 
begin 
    x := 100; 
    num := (x/30) *(30 - x1 - x2); 
    insert into ss_test_cut (cut) values (trunc (num,2));
end;

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question showing the actual vs expected results.

Comment: @ William Robertson Done .

Comment: The problem here is intermediate rounding in the calculation (the `x / 30`) which is then propagated via multiplication through the remaining operations. If computers implemented infinite-precision math this wouldn't matter - but they don't and it does. The solution is simply to rearrange the operations to delay the division until the end of the calculation as noted in my answer below. Thanks.